# Как вывести индекс третьего одинакового элемента массива?

Tags: c, массивы

Я немного не понимаю, я ввожу Х с клавиатуры, допустим 3, в этом массиве я должен вывести на экран индекс третьей тройки, если она есть, а она есть, у третьей тройки индекс 8, то есть мне нужно вывести 8, а у меня выводится 5 и 8, то есть ещё и индекс второй тройки, от индекса первой тройки я избавился, как теперь избавится от индекса второй?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define N 10

void main()
{
 int i, x;
 int A[N]={-2,0,3,-3,9,3,6,8,3,1};
 FILE *fout;

 setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");

 fout=fopen("mas1_1b.out","w");
 if(fout==NULL) {printf("Невозможно открыть файл mas1_1a.out\n");
 system("PAUSE");}

 fprintf(fout,"Исходный массив из %2d элементов: ", N);
 printf("Исходный массив из %2d элементов: ", N);

//Вывод исходного массива
fprintf(fout,"{"); printf("{");
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
fprintf(fout,"%d ", A[i]);
printf("%d ", A[i]);
}
   fprintf(fout,"}"); printf("}");
   fprintf(fout,"\n"); printf("\n");

 //Ввод заданного целого числа X
  fprintf(fout,"Введите x: "); printf("Введите x: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);

 //Вывод третьей тройки  массива
   for(i=0; i<N; i++)
 {
    if(A[i]==x) break;
    {
    for(i=x; i<N; i++)
    {
       if(A[i]==x) break;
       {
       for(i=x; i<N; i++)
          if(A[i]==x)
             {printf("%d", i);}
       }
    }
    }
  }

 fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: Что это за чушь: `for(i=x; i<N; i++)`? Какое отношение значение `x` имеет к индексам в массиве?

Comment: Что-то прямо жесть какая-то. То есть вы определили массив из `10` значений, при этом делите его по `3` - это значит, что `-2,0,3` раз, `3,9,3` два, `6,8,3` три, как это вы, определили. что последнее должно быть `8`, а не `3`? =) И вообще не понимаю, что есть `x`?

Comment: @And Х - это заданное целое число, которое вводится с клавиатуры, программа должна найти все элементы в массиве, которые равны Х и вывести индекс третьего по порядку слева направо

Comment: @And То есть если я ввожу Х=3, в массиве у меня три тройки, у меня должен вывестись индекс последней тройки слева направо, а её индекс 8, то есть должно вывестись 8, а выводится 5 и 8, то есть ещё и индекс второй тройки слева направо, как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй добавить счетчик до нужного кол-ва числа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну например сделать это так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 10

void main() {
    int i, x, n;
    int A[N]={-2,0,3,-3,9,3,6,8,3,1};
    FILE *fout;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    fout=fopen("mas1_1b.out","w");
    if(fout==NULL) {
        printf("Невозможно открыть файл mas1_1a.out\n");
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    fprintf(fout,"Исходный массив из %2d элементов: ", N);
    printf("Исходный массив из %2d элементов: ", N);
    //Вывод исходного массива
    fprintf(fout,"{"); printf("{");
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        fprintf(fout,"%d ", A[i]);
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fout,"}"); printf("}");
    fprintf(fout,"\n"); printf("\n");
    //Ввод заданного целого числа X
    fprintf(fout,"Введите x: "); 
    printf("Введите x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    //Вывод третьей тройки  массива
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if(A[i]==x) {
           n = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", n);
    fclose(fout);
}
```